# how to make padding align right with row in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using row to horizon some component in flutter, this is my code:

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      item.subName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8,bottom: 8.0,right: 1),
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 50,
                        height: 30.0,
                        child:RaisedButton(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            print("pressed");
                          },
                          child: Text("Subscribe"),
                        )
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
```

now I want the button `subscribe` align right, what should I do to make it work? I am tried like this but failed:

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8,bottom: 8.0,right: 1),
```

I am tried to make the button with one pixel of the screen, but it seems not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something like this:

[image]

You can set the `mainAxisAlignment` property of `Row` to `spaceBetween`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to add is padding which only surrounds the widget, it will not align the widget to right. it will add padding to the right side of the Widget.
In `Row()` widget make `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`. This will align the Subscribe button to right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want space between the widgets of the row.

```
 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  ),
```

To Align the widgets completely on the right.

```
       Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  ),
```

To make the widgets take up the space evenly in the row.

```
 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  ),
```